# Logging of Access control logs in VB .NET

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, logging, authentication, access-control

I'm new to VB .NET, I want to write a method that saves a new entry to the database every time someone tries to log in no matter if it is a successful or failed attempt. 
Also I need to capture the IP address of the machine where the attempt is performed. 
Any advice of where to start

Comment: Add the code you have tried and tell why it didn't work as expected.

Comment: Are you talking about logging into the computer, or just your application? If it's the computer, this data is already saved to the Windows event log, and you just need to request it when needed.

Answer (score 1):

I dont believe capturing ip can be done locally without a library for it, but if you dont mind an api call you can use ip-api.com

```
'Query location data
Dim Req As HttpWebRequest
Dim Ret As HttpWebResponse = Nothing
Dim SR As StreamReader
Req = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create("http://ip-api.com/json"), HttpWebRequest)
Ret = DirectCast(Req.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
SR = New StreamReader(Ret.GetResponseStream())
Dim Raw As String = Nothing
Raw = SR.ReadToEnd()
Dim JavaScriptSerialization As New JavaScriptSerializer()
Dim ipdata_object As New IPData()

ipdata_object = JavaScriptSerialization.Deserialize(Raw, ipdata_object.GetType)
dim ip_address as string = ipdata_object.query.tostring()
```

IPData Class

```
'IP Data API Deserialization classes for http://ip-api.com/json API response
<Serializable>
Class IPData
    Public asinfo As String
    Public city As String
    Public country As String
    Public countryCode As String
    Public isp As String
    Public lat As String
    Public lon As String
    Public org As String
    Public query As String
    Public region As String
    Public regionName As String
    Public status As String
    Public timezone As String
    Public zip As String
End Class
```

As for logging, depending on what you want to use, Mysql, CSV, Flatfile, etc

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    'SAVE FUNCTION
    Dim LogString as String = "User " + Username + " Attempted to login from " + ip_address + " Successfully/Failed"

    My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText("C://testfile.txt", inputString, True)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this for mysql database

```
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient
Imports System.Data.Sql
Imports System
Imports System.Data

Public Class LoginForm

    'These variables store information regarding the sql connection string, and the sql class callers.
    Dim connectionString As String = "Server=localhost; User Id=admin; Password=pass; Database=access_logs"
    Dim SQLConnection As MySqlConnection = New MySqlConnection

    Private Sub LoginButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles LoginButton.Click
        Dim username As String = "usernametextbox.text"
        Dim ip_address As String = ipfetchfunction()
        Dim status As String = Nothing

        If username.ToString() = "valid" And Password.ToString() = "valid" Then
            status = "authorized"
        Else
            status = "failed"
        End If

        LogAttempt(username, ip_address, status)
    End Sub

    Public Function LogAttempt(user_name As String, ip_address As String, login_status As String) As Boolean
        SQLConnection = New MySqlConnection()
        SQLConnection.ConnectionString = connectionString
        Dim sqlCommand As New MySqlCommand
        Dim str_logSql As String

        Try
            str_logSql = "insert into access_log (username, user_ip, login_status) values ('" + user_name + "','" + ip_address + "','" + login_status + "')"
            'MsgBox(str_logSql) uncomment for debugging
            sqlCommand.Connection = SQLConnection
            sqlCommand.CommandText = str_logSql 
            sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()

            Return True
        Catch ex As Exception
            Return False
            'MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString()) Uncomment for debugging
        End Try
    End Function
End Class
```